# Word document open error

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2003

MS word document in .doc format opens well Word 2003 & the same doc opened in Word 2010 compatibility mode. It prompts to save the doc.

There are several other docs, they never prompt to save either in 2010 or 2003.

How to find out why its prompting save?, or how to avoid this save dialog? what is causing the doc to save

Answer (score 1):

> Compatibility mode makes sure that content that is created in the 2007
>   Office system or in the 2010 Office system can be converted into a
>   form that earlier versions of Office can use.

Word may also be detecting something is corrupt or not compatible with the file and it needs you to save it so the issues can be fixed.

To see what the issues are, go to the `File` menu, click `Info`, and then under `Check for Issues`, click `Check Compatibility`.

[image]

Any issues found will be listed in the `Microsoft Word Compatibility Checker` window when the inspection is complete.

[image]

**To avoid the dialog in the future** - click the `Convert` button on the `Info` menu to convert the document to Word 2010 format and to enable all Word features.